# Work around for limited SIP connections of Adobe media server and adobe media gateway

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, adobe-media-server

Why is it that adobe allows only 5-25 SIP connections using adobe media server and adobe media gateway. This does not allow any application to scale. Can somebody please elaborate and provide a solution to this.

Comment: If you need to scale beyond 25 SIP connections, the obvious solution is to deploy multiple instances of Adobe Media Server.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe media server with Extended Server license provides 25 SIP connections. This is the way they have licensed their product. They say that they provide 5 sip connection trial with their professional, standard and starter license. You can check out this link [faq.html](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/adobe-media-server-extended/faq.html). And this link also [adobe-buying-Guide](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/adobe-media-server-extended/buying-guide-comparison.html)